# Failed to parse input string in BigQuery with parse_date

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a column 'appointment_date' in string formate representing a date dd.mm.yyyy.

In BiqQuery I am using the following query to find all appointments dates lying in the future:

```
SELECT appointment_date
FROM `appointments` 
where parse_date('%d.%m.%Y', appointment_date) > current_date()
```

BiqQuery returns the following error message: Failed to parse input string ""

Please advice.

Thanks,
Janine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `safe.parse()` to avoid the error:

```
where safe.parse_date('%d.%m.%Y', appointment_date) > current_date()
```

This will return `NULL` for invalid formats rather than an error.